# Is there a "Fastest Gun in the West" issue with self-answers?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, self-answer, fastest-gun

After talking with a moderator on Gaming.SE, StrixVaria, regarding a question issue I have, I'm largely curious if there is an unspoken or somewhat hidden rule of not self-answering if you are high rep and leaving the question to answers from other players?

Question in context: [How do I change my Profile Icon?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264690/how-do-i-change-my-profile-icon)

Chat transcript: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29471852#29471852

Context: I posted a question which I immediately self-answered. Some users found it fine to downvote but largely the issue was perhaps that I did not let other users answer the question first, especially as a high rep user.

I know about the so-called "Fastest gun in the west problem" but that doesn't pertain to self-answers.

Is there a "Fastest Gun in the West" issue with self-answers? Is there an issue with a high-rep user self answering first? Is there an unspoken rule in the whole of SE regarding high-rep users in conjunction with self answers?

Comment: The option *answer your own question* is on the *Ask Question* page. That isn't removed for high-reps. I don't see much of a problem. Do you want quality Q and A's or do you want *reputation for everyone*. I only care about the first but on smaller communities it might be different.

Comment: 0/10, expected self answer for meta rep farming. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. There is, however, an unspoken rule that basic questions from high reputation users may be downvoted whether or not they self-answered.<sup>1</sup>

Self-answered questions are subject to the same quality guidelines as all other questions. If Gaming.SE frowns upon guide questions, the existence of your (presumably high-quality) answer may not be enough to save the question.

---

<sup>1.</sup> In the C++ tag, a wraparound effect may apply if the question is [so incredibly basic that it gets 5000 votes](//stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator)

Comment: "_There is, however, an unspoken rule that basic questions from high reputation users may be downvoted whether or not they self-answered._" \*Makes face of extreme confusion. I thought we vote on posts and not on people here...

Answer (score 2):

This got nothing to do with "Fastest gun in the west" or the question being self answered, as far as I can see.

As the moderator clearly [said](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264690/how-do-i-change-my-profile-icon#comment369624_264690):

> This site isn't for guides

So it's matter of the question being off topic.

If you want to discuss the question being on topic or not, best place is the [per site meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It was of the moderator's opinion that it was a guide

Comment: @Ordis and judging by the votes, others agree with him. Personally I'm not active in that site enough to judge - but looks like the community of the site decided already.